# SQL query -- condition on a column value within a set

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to query something like this

```
SELECT * WHERE (ORDER_ID='AAA' or ORDER_ID='BBB');
```

I notice that's somehow significantly slower than running

```
SELECT * WHERE ORDER_ID='AAA';
SELECT * WHERE ORDER_ID='BBB';
```

Seperately. Is there a reason why? what's the fastest way of doing this?

I was thinking, a string comparison should be trivial. and I didn't have to send the query to the server twice. The first query should be faster.

I am using Oracle SQL.

Comment: Could you provide the [query execution plan](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_interp.htm#TGSQL277) ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux sorry I am new to this. what does query execution plan mean?

Comment: If you think like a human, you should know that if you are making two compare at same time of a table it should be faster than making two time one compare.

Comment: @xsami but a string comparison should be trivial. and I didn't have to send the query to the server twice.

Comment: You put `EXPLAIN PLAN` before the Select statement and it will spit out your execution plan for both. Also, you can try `SELECT * WHERE ORDER_ID IN ('AAA', 'BBB');` possibly might be quicker than your `OR` or the eventual `UNION ALL` you are working your way into.

Answer (score 0):

What he means is that when you use WHERE (cond1 or cond2), it is expanded automatically by the Oracle DB into another query. Depending on the execution plan, Oracle may decide to handle it as a UNION or UNION ALL. You can use `explain` to see how your queries are being expanded. [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm)